# Fragment not getting refreshed/called everytime

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Somehow my `Fragment` is not getting called everytime.

Here's the **issue**:
I have 3 tabs like so.

```
-------------------------------------
|Fragment1   Fragment2   Fragment3  |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
```

Whenever I tap on *Fragment1* and then *Fragment3*, the `onCreateView` of *Fragment3* is getting called. However, when I tap on *Fragment2* and then *Fragment3*, it doesn't.

I'm using a custom `TabsPagerAdapter` which extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Below is the required code snippet. (Please let me know if you need to see more code).
**TabsPagerAdapter**

```
    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String[] tabs = { "Fragment1", "Fragment2", "Fragment3" };
    List<Fragment> fragments;



    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<TabsPagerAdapter> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return fragments.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            String tag = createdFragment.getTag();
        return createdFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return fragments.size();
    }

}
```

**Fragment3:**

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context=activity;
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          ......
         Log.i("Blocked List","onCreateView called"); //This doesn't print
                                                      //sometimes
          getList();//It holds the list for ListView

  }
```

`Fragment1` is almost similar to `Fragment2` and `Fragment3`.

Help!

Comment: `onCreateView` is not called because `onCreateView` is called only when it (fragment) created by `ViewPager`. Take a look at `setUserVisibleHint` as other user said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution use fragments Override method which fires only when fragment is visible in ViewPager

```
 @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if(isVisibleToUser) {
                //fragment visible code
            }
            else{
            //fragment invisible code
              }
        }
```

Comment: you have a ListFragment you must put it in each fragment

Answer (score 0):

with this solution, every time the getItem() is called, a new Fragment is created. You could try to instantiate the Fragments lazily (i.e. in an array or a collection) and then return them when needed.

Be aware that you need to pass in a List of Fragments, not Adapter.

In my project, I use this code that usually works

```
public ProfilePagesAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,
                            @NonNull List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position).getTitle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be the `ProfileBaseFragment` in my case?

Comment: It would be your TabsPagerAdapter

Comment: This line `return fragments.get(position);` is showing Incompatible types: Required: `Fragment` Found: `TabsPagerAdapter`.  Any pointer?

Comment: Can you update the code you are using in the first post?

Comment: I think inplace of `ProfileBaseFragment` I need to put my fragment. But in that case it wont be generic. Can you show `ProfileBaseFragment`?

Comment: You can just use Fragment

Comment: It looks like you are passing the list of adapters, not the list of fragments to the constructor

Comment: From the code, I see that the second parameter is a List of TabsPagerAdapter... Am I wrong?

Comment: What is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: pls check my question. I have mentioned my issue

Comment: Yes, I meant if changing the adapter does not change the issue. How do you call the adapter?